# updating the angular input field value in another tab

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two ionic tabs and each having different forms. I want to set the second tab field value(modal) when i move to second tab .

### controller

```
$scope.familyDetailsObj = {
      "familyDetils":  {
        "fatherNm":""       
      }
    }
```

When click on the 'continue' btn i am passing values in the following way,

```
$scope.continueBtn = function(tabindex){
      if(tabindex == 1){
         $scope.familyDetailsObj.familyDetils.fatherNm = "xyz";
         CustomerService.setFamilyDetails($scope.familyDetailsObj);
         $scope.og = CustomerService.getFamilyDetails();
         console.log($scope.og.familyDetils.fatherNm); //xyz
         $scope.familyDetailsObj.familyDetils.fatherNm = $scope.og.familyDetils.fatherNm;
}
```

### factory

```
.factory('CustomerService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var familyDetails = {}
    return{
        setFamilyDetails : function(familyDetailsObj){
            familyDetails = familyDetailsObj;
        },
        getFamilyDetails : function(){
            return familyDetails;
        }     
    };
}])
```

### view in the second tab

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="familyDetailsObj.familyDetils.fatherNm" name="fatherNm">
```

I have updated in the codepen, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVPNWJ

after clicking on the **continue** button the model value not setting.

Comment: what is problem u are facing.

Comment: try $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.familyDetailsObj.familyDetils.fatherNm = $scope.og.familyDetils.fatherNm;
        });

Comment: not able to setting the updated value in the field(i.e, xyz)

Comment: paste code of another tab controller, how do you initializing that?

Comment: if(tabindex==1) i am going to the second tab(i.e, same controller)

Comment: I think the data setting has no issue but tab refresh is the issue. Check in the browser console whether you are able to set the below value.
`$scope.familyDetailsObj.familyDetils.fatherNm = $scope.og.familyDetils.fatherNm;`

Comment: i am able display the value in console but not updating in the view